# What is the difference on APIClient.enforce_csrf_checks and APIClient.handler.enforce_csrf_checks

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I noticed that when I create a handler

```
newClient = APIClient(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
```

that

```
newClient.enforce_csrf_checks = False
```

but

```
newClient.handler.enforce_csrf_checks = True
```

What is the difference?  I ask this because I have an existing API Client and I want to know the difference:

```
class ModifyTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client.enforce_csrf_checks = True          # Do this?
        self.client.handler.enforce_csrf_checks = True  # Or Do this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize an `APIClient`, [a `ForceAuthClientHandler` is initialized](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/713333d3544c22ec90c6c32c7a499b2fbe70d415/rest_framework/test.py#L137) with the value of `enforce_csrf_checks` ([default is `False`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/713333d3544c22ec90c6c32c7a499b2fbe70d415/rest_framework/test.py#L135)). This is what `client.handler` is, and it's why `client.handler.enforce_csrf_checks` is `True` in your case.

It looks like `client.enforce_csrf_checks` is preferred over `client.handler.enforce_csrf_checks`, but it will fall back if needed.